# How to write directive to hide div clicking on it or anywhere on page?

Tags: angularjs

I am writing directive for first time.What i am trying to do is when user click on div it open that div, if div is opened and user click anywhere on page to close that div and if div is closed and user click anywhere on page that div stay closed. My html looks like this:

```
<div id="loggedIn" close-logged-in class="fade-show-hide" ng-show="loggedInOpened" default-display='block' ng-cloak>
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LoggedInPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

My angular:

```
   $scope.toggleLoggedIn = function () {
        $scope.loggedInOpened = !$scope.loggedInOpened;
        $scope.languagesOpened = false;
        $scope.loginOpened = false;


    };
```

And my directive looks like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module("mainModule").directive('closeLoggedIn',['$window', function ($window) {
    return {

        // bind a local scope (i.e. on link function scope) property 
        // to the value of default-display attribute in our target <div>.
        scope: {
            defaultDisplay: '@'
        },

        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var el = element[0];


            el.style.display = scope.defaultDisplay || 'block';  

            angular.element($window).bind('click', function(){        

                if(scope.defaultDisplay == 'block')
                el.style.display = 'none';

            });
        } 

    };
}]);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestions for what? You haven't defined any problems

Comment: Problem is that when i click on div its not show, it add display:none on that div and if i remove it manually it works then

Comment: you got a jsfiddle? please

Comment: That problem statement isn't very clear. Please update question with proper problem statement and what you expect to happen. Perhaps you want to check if div is the target.

Comment: @JoshStevens on plunker it works for me but when i use it on my project its not

Comment: @charlietfl i explain what i expect to happend and what happend i dont know what is not clea to your?

Comment: its anywhere on the page or particularly anywhere in the div?

Comment: @Jagadeesh when i click on div i want to open that div , and if its open if i click anywhere out of that div i want to close that div ....but if div is close and if i click anyqhere out of that div i want that div stay closed...any sense to you? :)

Comment: i think you can use ng-hide or ng-show. Use this the div which u want to show and hide. Also that div should on the another div means that `<div class="mainDiv" > <div class="divUNeedToHide"> </div></div>` So by click the mainDiv you can hide and show divUNeedToHide.

Comment: @uzhas then when do u need the div will open again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83728/discussion-between-uzhas-and-jagadeesh).

Comment: You can't click on an element that is hidden. Problem explanation is still confusing. Please create demo that displays your issue

Comment: @charlietfl what im trying to do is this http://plnkr.co/edit/lx87lJraTOWGtQHt0dev?p=preview but i need to adopt it to my own project

Comment: So why are you manipulating the element in your directive and not changing scope the way the demo does? Provide a demo of your code so we can see the problem

Comment: i dont know ..like i said this is my first directive so im not sure what i need to do

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"   ng-show="userclick==1" class="sample">
    <div class="test" ng-hide="hideDiv" > hideDiv </div>
</div>
```

Use ng-show
modify the value of `var userclick` to zero on whatever condition you mentioned and the div will be hidden till the `userclick` value is not 1.
Be sure the the value is getting applied updated.
print the updated value to console.
use

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.userclick = 0;
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

As my understanding I have created a sample structure it might be help full for you please check..

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"   ng-click="testing() "class="sample">
    <div class="test" ng-hide="hideDiv" > hideDiv </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.hideDiv = false;
    $scope.testing = function () {
        if ($scope.hideDiv) {
        $scope.hideDiv = false;
        } else {
            $scope.hideDiv = true;
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.sample{
    background-color: red;    
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why is there argument in view for function but none in declaration? Doing this from controller doesn't make sense.